# Expression for the order number of domino tiles

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

The domino tiles can be listed in an orderly way as shown in the figure :

[image]

[figure link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8VUj.jpg)

**Write an expression** such that given two variables ("minor" and "major") where "minor" is the  lowest value and "major" the highest value of a domino tile, **calculate its order number associated with the previous figure.**

**Example** : given a domino tile with numbers 1 and 5, the expression must calculate the order number 11. Given a tile with numbers 4 and 6 the expression must calculate the order number 24

---

From  the domino tile with numbers (0,0) to (1,6) the expression "6 * minor + major" works but  from the next domino tile, the expression begins to fail and I can't find a general expression. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the minor number and $y$ be the major number.  It looks easier to me to count downward because there is one tile with $x=6$, two tiles with $x=5$ and so on.  There are $\frac 12(6-x)(7-x)$ tiles in the rows with minor numbers greater than $x$ so the last index in the row above $x$ is $28-\frac 12(6-x)(7-x)$.  Now we count down $7-y$ tiles in the current row, giving a final result of $$21-\frac 12(6-x)(7-x)+y$$

Comment: If $x=2$ and  $y=2$ your function give 23 ... but the tile (2,2) is in the position 13

Comment: @Daniel:  I had added $7-y$ instead of subtracting.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: Your function is the same of ShenLei but you answered the question first, so I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

(13 - minor) minor/2 + major

You can simplify the problem by noticing major must in form of F(minor) + major.