# How many dominoes makes a complete game?

Tags: combinatorics

The dominoes are labelled with the numbers $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$.

Any possible combination of two (not necessarily different) numbers can occur. How many dominoes makes a complete game?

$$$$

The number "0" can be combined with each of the 7 numbers.

Then "1" can also be combined with each of the 7 numbers but we have already considered the case "0" + "1".

Then "2" can also be combined with each of the 7 numbers but we have already considered the cases "0" + "2" and "1" + "2".

And so on.

So a complete game consists of $7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot \ldots = 7!$ dominoes.

Is that correct?

Comment: Note also that $7! = 5040$ domino pieces would not fit into a standard box :)

Comment: So I count some combinations several times. But how do we count then the combinations? @MartinR

Comment: The domino tiles are $0/0, 0/1, \ldots 0/6$, then $1/1, 1/2, \ldots, 1/6$, and so on. That makes $7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 28$ pieces.

Comment: Here is a nice picture: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2488231/42969.

Comment: Ahh ok! So we don't use a specific formula, we just add all possibilities, right? @MartinR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider a domino set where the number of dots on a square ranges from zero to $n$. ($n=6$ corresponds to the standard domino game.)

Every domino piece can be uniquely identified as a pair $(a, b)$ of integers with
$$ \tag{$*$}
 0 \le a \le b \le n.
$$

- For $a=0$ we have $n+1$ choices for $b$.
- For $a=1$ we have $n$ choices for $b$.
- ...
- For $a=n$ we have $1$ choice for $b$.

So the total number of pieces is
$$
 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n + (n+1) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
$$
from the well-known formula for [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Another way to obtain this result is to write $(*)$ as
$$
 0 \le a < b+1 \le n+1
$$
which shows that the number of pieces is equal to the number of [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of two objects out of $n+2$ objects, that is the binomial coefficient
$$
 \binom{n+2}{2} = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{1 \cdot 2} \, .
$$

Comment: Great!! Your answer is very helpful!! Thank you very much!! :-)